# How the IP address is recognized in the Internet in multicast?

Tags: multicast

I am referring to "[Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html)" from Oracle Java Tutorial:

Both the server and the client use the group identifier to identify they belong to the same group.
But the group ID is likely to be duplicate in the Internet (and actually I goolged and it is said the group identifier does not need to be unique)

Then how come the client on other side of the Internet can know it belongs to the same group of the server?
Would you give me some links to describe the process?

If server A mutlicasts audio streams, server B multicasts video streams. 
Server A uses a group ID 203.0.113.0:4446
Server B happens to uses the group ID 203.0.113.0:4446. 
How come the clients in the Internet knows the differences?
But since Server A does not know the existence of Server B at all, A do not know how to choose a unique group ID, as the uniqueness in the IP address.

It seems I cross some articles, talking about adding some MAC address. 
But in the Oracle Java Tutorial, the coding for the client does not mention MAC address at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'reorganized' in your title, but the client *doesn't* 'know it belongs to the same group [as] the server'. It only knows that it belongs to the group defined by the IP address. If there are multiple hosts sending to that IP address it will receive from all of them.

Comment: Sorry, it should be "recognized" (the automatic correction chose another word reorganized). I do not understand what you said: I mean, if server A mutlicasts audio streams, server B multicasts video streams. Server A uses a group ID 203.0.113.0:4446, Server B happens to uses the group ID 203.0.113.0:4446. How come the clients in the Internet knows the differences?

Comment: It can't. There isn't a difference.

Comment: So in the Internet, as a client, it wants to get the stream from Server A. How to uniquely identify the stream from Server A?

Comment: It just has to ignore any data it doesn't understand.

Comment: How about Server A and Server B both stream the video. So the client can understand data both from A and B. Does that mean the client will frames both from A and B?